# How do we combine drop n elements from a list and take n elements from a list?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

We can create function that take n elements from a list, and drop n elements from a list, as the following:

```
let rec take n l = 
  if n = 0 then 
    [] 
  else 
    match l with 
      h::t -> h :: take (n - 1) t
```

Similarily,

```
let rec drop n l = 
  if n = 0 then 
    l 
  else 
    match l with 
      h::t -> drop (n - 1) t
```

But how do we combine take and drop function such that it returns a pair with the result of dropping n elements and adding n elements from a list `l`?

Answer (score 0):

```
let rec add_drop n l = 
  if n = 0 then 
    ([], l) 
  else 
    match l with 
      h::t -> 
        let (a, b) = add_drop (n - 1) t in 
        (h::a, b)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

This is also available in [ocaml-containers](https://github.com/c-cube/ocaml-containers) as [`take_drop`](https://c-cube.github.io/ocaml-containers/last/containers/CCList/index.html#val-take_drop):

```
val take_drop : int -> 'a t -> 'a t * 'a t
```

And in Jane Street's [Base](https://github.com/janestreet/base) as [`split_n`](https://v3.ocaml.org/p/base/v0.15.0/doc/Base/List/index.html#val-split_n)

```
val split_n : 'a t -> int -> 'a t * 'a t
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a tail-recursive approach, with a helper function that builds up the first N elements in an extra argument, originally in reverse order, and then reversing that list before returning it. That way it takes the same stack space no matter how big N is.

```ml
let split n lst =
  let rec helper n lst head =
    if n = 0 then
      head, lst
    else
      match lst with
      | car :: cdr -> helper (n - 1) cdr (car :: head)
      | [] -> head, [] (* List is shorter than n *) in
  let head, tail = helper n lst [] in
  List.rev head, tail
```

Comment: Thanks! definitely should use tail recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion 101: we need a base case. If `n` is zero, the list of elements taken is empty, and the list of elements left is just the input list. We can use just a `match`. no need for an `if`.

```
let rec take_drop n lst =
  match n, lst with
  | 0, _ -> ([], lst)
```

Now, if `n` is *not* zero, and the list is empty, then we can't proceed. Let's raise an exception. *We're going to assume that `n` is never negative for simplicity.*

```
let rec take_drop n lst =
  match n, lst with
  | 0, _ -> ([], lst)
  | _, [] -> failwith "n is too large for list"
```

Now, what's tricky is what we do if `n` is not zero *and* the list is non-empty. We need to recursively call `take_drop` on the tail of the list, decrementing `n` by one. Both of these will update those pieces of data to converge on the bases cases that terminate the recursion.

```
let rec take_drop n lst =
  match n, lst with
  | 0, _ -> ([], lst)
  | _, [] -> failwith "n is too large for list"
  | _, h::t ->
    let (a, b) = take_drop (n - 1) t in
    (h :: a, b)
```

```
# take_drop 3 [1;2;3;4;5;6];;
- : int list * int list = ([1; 2; 3], [4; 5; 6])
# take_drop 2 [1;2;3;4;5;6];;
- : int list * int list = ([1; 2], [3; 4; 5; 6])
```

Now, this doesn't work great for very large lists and very large values of `n` because it's not tail-recursive. One of the most idiomatic methods for getting it there is going to be using an accumulator.

We pass an extra argument to the function in which we build up the return value. At the end of the recursion we return the accumulator argument.

```
let rec take_drop n lst (f, s as acc) =
  match n, lst with
  | 0, _ -> acc
  | _, [] -> failwith "n is too large for list"
  | _, h::t -> take_drop (n - 1) t (h::f, t)
```

```
# take_drop 2 [1;2;3;4;5;6] ([], []);;
- : int list * int list = ([2; 1], [3; 4; 5; 6])
```

Oops. Because of how we built up the first list, it has to be reversed.

```
let rec take_drop n lst (f, s) =
  match n, lst with
  | 0, _ -> (List.rev f, s)
  | _, [] -> failwith "n is too large for list"
  | _, h::t -> take_drop (n - 1) t (h::f, t)
```

And we don't really need to pass the tail of the list twice.

```
let rec take_drop n lst acc =
  match n, lst with
  | 0, _ -> (List.rev acc, lst)
  | _, [] -> failwith "n is too large for list"
  | _, h::t -> take_drop (n - 1) t (h::acc)
```

```
# take_drop 2 [1;2;3;4;5;6] [];;
- : int list * int list = ([1; 2], [3; 4; 5; 6])
```

We can "hide" the extra empty list argument by either shadowing the `take_drop` name, or by using a locally scoped function.

```
# let take_drop n lst = take_drop n lst [];;
val take_drop : int -> 'a list -> 'a list * 'a list = <fun>
# take_drop 2 [1;2;3;4;5;6];;
- : int list * int list = ([1; 2], [3; 4; 5; 6])
```

Or:

```
let take_drop n lst =
  let rec aux n lst acc =
    match n, lst with
    | 0, _ -> (List.rev acc, lst)
    | _, [] -> failwith "n is too large for list"
    | _, h::t -> aux (n - 1) t (h::acc)
  in
  aux n lst []
```